# Best way to set the limit of a right arrow of a thumb strip?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my `sideThumb` function with comments. `this.panos` is the number of thumbs, and `this.translateX` is the number of pixels that the thumbs are moved.

```
slideThumbs (direction) { // slide to left or right
  const thumbWidth = 160 + 6 // plus padding
  const visibleThumbsWidth = thumbWidth * 5 // slide 5 thumbs at a time

  // exclude last thumb
  const totalThumbsWidth = thumbWidth * (this.panos.length - 1)
  if (direction === 'left' && this.translateX !== 0) {
    this.translateX += visibleThumbsWidth
  }
  if (direction === 'right' && this.translateX !== -totalThumbsWidth) {
    this.translateX -= visibleThumbsWidth
  }
}
```

End result:

```
transform: translate(-830px, 0px); // clicking the right arrow one time
transform: translate(-1660px, 0px); // and two times
```

Setting the limit of the left arrow is easy: don't left the function run if `this.translateX` is `0`. It's harder to set the limit of the right arrow.  Using `-totalThumbsWidth` is not reliable because having `11` and `14` panos should bring the same result (enable the user to press the right arrow 2 times).

[image]

What's the best way to address this?

**EDIT:**

Some math that I made:

```
 6 thumbs => can click right arrow 1 time
 11 thumbs => can click right arrow 2 times
 16 thumbs => can click right arrow 3 times

 5 * x + 1 = 16 // this is how I get x in the third example
 x = (this.panos.length - 1) / 5 // what to do with this?
```

I'm sure I can use this in a math calculation.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Use Number of Slides in your padding calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this, but without a fiddle I can't verify that it works in your particular case

```
slideThumbs (direction) { // slide to left or right
  const thumbWidth = 160 + 6 // plus padding
  const currentTilePosition = (this.translateX / thumbWidth) + 5; // get the current number for the last visible tile / we +5 because translateX starts at 0
  const tilesToGo = (this.panos.length - currentTilePosition) - 1; // how many tiles to go?

  var incrementThumbs = thumbWidth * 5 // slide 5 thumbs at a time

  if (direction === 'right' && tilesToGo < 5) {
      if (tilesToGo === 0) {
       incrementThumbs = 0;
      } else if {
       incrementThumbs = thumbWidth * tilesToGo; 
      }
  }

  if (direction === 'left' && currentTilesPosition % 5 !== 0) {
     incrementThumbs = thumbWidth * (currentTilesPosition % 5);
  }

  if (direction === 'left' && this.translateX !== 0) {
    this.translateX += incrementThumbs
  }
  if (direction === 'right') {
    this.translateX -= incrementThumbs
  }
}
```

Doing it this way will also ensure that the last tile is always flush with the right side of the screen in cases where the total amount of tiles is not a multiple of 5, I have also added some code to facilitate moving left from such a case, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I finally set the limit like this:

```
  const thumbWidth = 166 // thumb width plus padding 160 + 6
  const visibleThumbsWidth = thumbWidth * 5

  const rightArrowClicks = (-this.translateX / thumbWidth) + 6
  console.log('TRANSLATE LENGTH', (-this.translateX / thumbWidth) + 6)
  console.log('PANO LENGTH', this.panos.length)
  if (direction === 'left' && this.translateX !== 0) {
    this.translateX += visibleThumbsWidth
  }
  if (direction === 'right' && rightArrowClicks <= this.panos.length) {
    this.translateX -= visibleThumbsWidth
  }
```

`-this.translateX / thumbWidth` is the number of thumbs that have been moved to the left. As for 6 ... not sure why it works with that number. I reached to this solution with the console logs. I'll be glad if someone can explain to me my own code.